# Show that if $a_n > 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{(a_n)}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Show that if $a_n > 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{(a_n)}$ converges.

I conjecture that the final term of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{(a_n)}$ only goes to $0$ if the inside function is a ratio with highest degree in the denominator, and only converges if that function $f$ is at least $f < \dfrac{1}{x^p}$. So this implies for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin{(a_n)}$ to converge, then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n)$ must converge.

However, I am suspicious that my reasoning may be somewhat lacking. Insight?

Comment: @Winther Solution-verification. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Just call for the algebra of limits, this time for composition of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate approach: If $\sum a_n < \infty$, then $\lim a_n = 0$, and hence
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n} = 1
$$
Now the convergence of $\sum \sin(a_n)$ follows from the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

- If  $a_n > 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges then $a_n$ converges to $0$
- If $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, and $a_n$ converges to $0$ then for some $n_0$, you have $0 \lt a_n \lt \pi$ for all $n \gt n_0$
- If  $0 \lt a_n \lt \pi$ then $\sin(a_n) \lt a_n$.